# Can I have a project-specific custom code deprecation message using eslint?

Tags: node.js, gulp, eslint

I have a `node.js` project that checks itself for code consistency according to rules specified in `.eslintrc` using `gulp` and `gulp-eslint`.

Now, I would like to have it throw custom deprecation warnings when it encounters a certain `require`:

```
const someModule = require('myDeprecatedModule');
// Warning: myDeprecatedModule is deprecated. Use myNewModule in stead.
```

Is this possible in a simple way that will be picked up by IDE's too?

- Using `.eslint`
- No custom plugin to be published and installed using `npm`
- Local code only that can be pushed to the repository, nothing global
- No custom code in `node_modules`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule [`no-restricted-modules`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-modules) does exactly this: it disallows requiring certain modules.

The names of the deprecated modules must be coded in the configuration. So in order to disallow the deprecated `myDeprecatedModule` you would add this setting to your .eslintrc file under the `"rules"` section.

```
"no-restricted-modules": ["error", "myDeprecatedModule"]
```

I don't think it's possible to customize the error message though. That would be possible with a custom plugin.

Comment: Upvoted. This seems to be a good middle-ground. I'll check it out. I'll leave the question open for now to see if anyone comes up with a way to have more tailored friendly error messages that don't require an explanation to other devs. _("No, they are not restricted, but, ...")_

Comment: There is no other built-in option. There's a ticket open to add enhancement to this rule to allow for custom messages here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7532